# std::move between std::string and std::vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, string, vector, std, unsigned-char

I am working with 2 libraries. One takes in and returns `std::string`s while the other uses `std::vector<unsigned char>`s.

It would be good if I could steal the underlying arrays from `std::string` and `std::vector<unsigned char>` and be able to move them into each other without the excessive copying.

ATM I use something like:

```
const unsigned char* raw_memory =
    reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(string_value.c_str()),
std::vector<unsigned char>(raw_memory, raw_memory + string_value.size();
```

And the other way:

```
std::string(
    reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&vector_value[0]),
    vector_value.size());
```

It'd be far better to be able to define a:

```
std::string move_into(std::vector<unsigned char>&&);
std::vector<unsigned char> move_into(std::string&&);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not possible.

The `vector` and `string` class do not provide way to steal from anything else than `vector` or `string` **respectively**. They are not meant to exchange content.

The problem issue is that `vector` and `string` may have widely different underlying representations. Typically in gcc for example, `string` use the oldish COW (Copy On Write) "optimization", which is widely different from the typical `vector` representation (usually just a triple of pointers/size_t attributes).

If you are dealing with raw bytes, blame the library that decided to put them into `string`, and refactor it if you can.

Otherwise: copy. The `reinterpret_cast` should not be necessary because `char` and `unsigned char` have implicit casts between them (and now `char` is often `unsigned` by default).

Comment: C++11 explicitly disallows copy on write, doesn't it? Unless they keep it under the "so long as it behaves as if we complied with the spec" law. I think small string optimization has been the way to go for a while.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the initialization using iterators. Have a look [here](http://ideone.com/NdPn0)

EDIT: pasting the code so that you don't have to go to ideone. Still leaving the link so that you can play arround with the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        string a = "Hello world";
        vector<unsigned char> v(a.begin(), a.end());
        for (int i= 0 ;i<  v.size(); ++i) {
           cout << v[i] << endl;
        }
        string s(v.begin(), v.end());
        cout << s << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course this isn't any different from his solution, regarding the neccessary copies (what his question is about) and thus doesn't answer his question in any way. It's much cleaner than his solution, though, but a comment would have sufficed for this.

Comment: @Christian why much cleaner? `string& assign (const char* s, size_t n);` should do a memcpy, while  `template <class InputIterator>
   string& assign (InputIterator first, InputIterator last); ` emulates it