# How to convert std::string to std::vector<std::byte> in C++17?

Tags: c++, byte

How do I convert a `std::string` to a `std::vector<std::byte>` in C++17? 
**Edited:** I am filling an asynchronous buffer due to retrieving data as much as possible. So, I am using `std::vector<std::byte>` on my buffer and I want to convert string to fill it.

```
std::string gpsValue;
gpsValue = "time[.........";
std::vector<std::byte> gpsValueArray(gpsValue.size() + 1);
std::copy(gpsValue.begin(), gpsValue.end(), gpsValueArray.begin());
```

but I am getting this error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘char’ to ‘std::byte’ in assignment
        *__result = *__first;
        ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: I added the reason on the description

Comment: Use std::transform?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use new std::byte type in places where old-style unsigned char is needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150738/how-to-use-new-stdbyte-type-in-places-where-old-style-unsigned-char-is-needed)

Comment: Related, see [How to convert std::string to std::vector<uint8_t>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41737254/608639), [std::move between std::string and std::vector<unsigned char>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10445042/608639) (and friends).

Comment: Why is your vector **one** element larger than your string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) should work:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string gpsValue;
    gpsValue = "time[.........";
    std::vector<std::byte> gpsValueArray(gpsValue.size() + 1);
    std::transform(gpsValue.begin(), gpsValue.end(), gpsValueArray.begin(),
                   [] (char c) { return std::byte(c); });
    for (std::byte b : gpsValueArray)
    {
        std::cout << int(b) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
116
105
109
101
91
46
46
46
46
46
46
46
46
46
0
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::byte` is not supposed to be a general purpose 8-bit integer, it is only supposed to represent a blob of raw binary data. Therefore, it does (rightly) not support assignment from `char`.

You could use a `std::vector<char>` instead - but that's basically what `std::string` is.

---

If you really want to convert your string to a vector of `std::byte` instances, consider using `std::transform` or a range-`for` loop to perform the conversion.

Comment: That's weird, `byte` should have the same size as `char`, no matter how many bits it contains.

Comment: @liliscent `float`s generally have the same size as `int`s (32 bits), doesn't mean that it's OK to do bit-by-bit copy on a simple assignment.

Comment: @DanM. You missed my point. My comment was to say the explanation in the answer, especially the mentioning of 8-bits, doesn't justify the non-existence of assignment from `char` to `byte`. IMO, that assignment operator *should* be defined.

Comment: @liliscent it seems like you are missing the point. `std::byte` is not a character type and is not an arithmetic type. It's made specifically to represent memory bits.  Having arbitrary implicit conversions would break it purpose and demote it to just being a typedef for unsigned char, which it is not.